# iOS iCloud Backup on New Device Smaller

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup

I recently bought a new iPhone. When setting up my new device I restored the backup from my old phone using iCloud.

When I look at my iCloud manage storage settings it says the old device backup is 7GB about and the new device backup is 4.5GB.

If anything the backup size should be larger.

At first glance everything transferred over to the new device. There were a few apps such as Google Authenticator where data didn't transfer over. But for the most part all of my data got transferred over.

I also can't remember deleting any major data since restoring the backup. Could be wrong about that tho.

Is there any reason why the new backup would be about 3.5GB smaller then the backup I restored from? Do you think it's safe to delete the old backup?